# How to add a react component in Soft.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im facing a problem where im trying to add a react component or recode it inline html in softr.io and i need help, if there is anyway to do it.

```
 <div id="root"></div>

<!-- Load React. -->
<!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<!-- Load your React component. -->
<script src="states_clock.js"></script>

<!-- Example script to create a React component and render it. -->
<script>
  // Define your React component.
  function StatesClock() {
    return <div>Hello, React!</div>;
  }

  // Render the component in the root element.
  ReactDOM.render(<StatesClock />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so defining `JSX` inside of a script tag is impossible if you do not use some sort of compiler such as `babel` which can "understand" `JSX` and compile it into regular `JavaScript` for the browser to understand.

First, you'll need to include babel as a script in your HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Then you'll need to set the script `type` attribute to "text/babel":

```
<script type="text/babel">
```

Here is the complete, working example based on the code you provided:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Test</title>

  <base href="/" />

  <meta name="color-scheme" content="light" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/images/logo.png" />

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Ionic App" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="states_clock.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
  // Your React code here
  function StatesClock() {
    return <div>Hello, React!</div>;
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<StatesClock />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
</html>
```

Note the console log, it is warning you that you are using [deprecated rendering code](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom#deprecated-apis). You should use [createRoot](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/createRoot) instead.